# Installing Vmware ESX on Solaris server

Tags: security, solaris, vmware, emulators

I have been told to install VMWare ESX on the Solaris server, but I could not find resources about this issue on the web, how is that possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it misunderstands the concepts of a bare metal hypervisor (such as ESX) to a hypervisor that may be embedded into an OS

Comment: I think you misunderstand what you've been ask for. Solaris is a hardware platform. ESX is a virtualisation hypervisor that rely a lot on hardware to work. You better understand what you've been asked for I'm not sure what you ask for is possible.

Comment: @Kiwy you maybe right, i am not totaly sure about what i asked but i am sure that the CTO asked me to install a hypervisor (ESX for example) on solaris.

Comment: I would tend to leave this open, actually; misunderstandings can be corrected with Answers. Since the main environment appears to be Solaris, I would consider this question on-topic.  I would recommend removing the request for *hints* and leaving "is it possible?"  As far as benefits go, that gets into broad territory and also diverges from the introduction of "install ESX on Solaris". Please focus your question(s) on an individual topic each. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMWare ESX is a bare metal hypervisor installed from the ground up on Intel architecture machines.

If we are talking about Solaris for Intel, we are talking about VmWare ESX on the physical machine itself where now Solaris runs being reinstalled witj VmWare ESX (probably, I would double check).

Otherwise, Solaris for Intel can be installed on a VM in a VMWare ESX server.

Side note: If the question is about an old Sparc Solaris, that does not support VmWare.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no vmware for OpenSolaris and ESX is the bare metal thing. You have got OpenSolaris 10 running in ESX and not the other way around.